# Is there a way to prevent user interaction pausing animations?

Tags: javascript, html, animation

I have an animation that runs on a webpage. As soon as I interact with the page on a touch device the animation stops. This does not happen on the desktop. I'm testing on Chrome and Safari on the iPad.

Is this a deliberate choice browser vendors have made? Is there any way around this?

You can test this by going to this [JSFiddle page](http://jsfiddle.net/fBFkA/9/) on a touch device.

This is the JavaScript I'm using:

```
var offset = 0;
var requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame ||
                                              window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
                                              window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
                                              window.msRequestAnimationFrame;

$('.box').on('click', function() {
  animateWithAnimationFrame();
});

function animateWithAnimationFrame() {
  if (offset === 500)
    return;
  offset++;
  $('.box').attr('style', '-webkit-transform: translate3d(' + offset + 'px, 0, 0)');
  requestAnimationFrame(animateWithAnimationFrame);   
}
```

I also tried animation with setTimeout, but that makes no difference.

Thanks.

Comment: Not happening on Chrome for Android

Comment: Yuriy - thanks for testing. Perhaps this is iOS specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Android browser touch events stop display being updated inc. canvas/elements - How to work around?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10246305/android-browser-touch-events-stop-display-being-updated-inc-canvas-elements-h) for similar problem.

Actually, dismissing only touchstart on the document (after animation is started) does the trick: http://jsfiddle.net/fBFkA/17/:

```
function touchHandlerDummy(e) {
    return false;
}
document.addEventListener("touchstart", touchHandlerDummy, false);
```