# Applications hangs and touch events does not work in Samsung devices

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, ibm-mobilefirst, samsung-mobile

I am using Worklight 6.1.0. I have created a worklight app and also added jquery mobile 1.4.2 library in it. When I tried testing the in multiple devices it works fine except in samsung devices.
The app hangs in samsung devices(I tried with Samsung Galaxy Grand Duos(Android O.S - 4.2.2) and Samsung Galaxy S3(Android O.S - 4.3)) and touch events does not work and it gives following errors :These are DDMS logs :

```
07-05 15:21:25.186: E/ViewRootImpl(29863): sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
07-05 15:21:25.341: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(29863): Ignore this event
07-05 15:21:25.351: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(29863): Ignore this event
07-05 15:21:25.351: D/WebView(29863): onSizeChanged - w:720 h:778
07-05 15:21:26.631: D/dalvikvm(29863): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4208K, 40% free 12330K/20224K, paused 14ms, total 14ms
07-05 15:21:26.816: V/WebViewInputDispatcher(29863): blockWebkitDraw
07-05 15:21:26.816: V/WebViewInputDispatcher(29863): blockWebkitDraw lockedfalse
07-05 15:21:29.261: V/WebViewInputDispatcher(29863): blockWebkitDraw
07-05 15:21:29.261: V/WebViewInputDispatcher(29863): blockWebkitDraw lockedfalse
07-05 15:21:29.576: D/webview(29863): blockWebkitViewMessage= false
07-05 15:21:29.676: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(29863): Ignore this event
07-05 15:21:29.681: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(29863): Ignore this event
07-05 15:21:29.681: D/WebView(29863): onSizeChanged - w:720 h:1230
07-05 15:21:29.711: V/WebViewInputDispatcher(29863): blockWebkitDraw
07-05 15:21:29.711: V/WebViewInputDispatcher(29863): blockWebkitDraw lockedfalse
07-05 15:21:29.931: D/webview(29863): blockWebkitViewMessage= false
07-05 15:21:29.976: V/WebViewInputDispatcher(29863): blockWebkitDraw
07-05 15:21:29.976: V/WebViewInputDispatcher(29863): blockWebkitDraw lockedfalse
07-05 15:21:30.181: D/webview(29863): blockWebkitViewMessage= false
07-05 15:21:30.191: V/WebViewInputDispatcher(29863): blockWebkitDraw
07-05 15:21:30.191: V/WebViewInputDispatcher(29863): blockWebkitDraw lockedfalse
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a bug in Android.

See here:

- [Phonegap on Galaxy S3 ignores touch events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12862347/phonegap-on-galaxy-s3-ignores-touch-events)
- [Android browser touch events stop display being updated inc. canvas/elements - How to work around?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10246305/android-browser-touch-events-stop-display-being-updated-inc-canvas-elements-h/10495741#10495741)
- https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19827
- http://backtothecode.blogspot.co.il/2009/10/javascript-touch-and-gesture-events.html